# Access the GPS of Android device in a Web Application

Tags: android, web-applications

We are trying to access the GPS of the Android Tablet from the web application opened in the Android browser.

We are not developing Android application. All we want to do is, just browse the web application from the Android browser and in that we would like to access the in-built GPS in the Android device.

Right now, we are using HTML 5 geolocation API, but those values are approximate.
We would like to have more accurate values, so we want to access GPS in the Android device from the web application.

We are not going with Android app because the user may use this application in iOS too.

Appreciate the help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 geolocation API is the best you'll be able to do, at least in a crossplatform way. But it shouldn't be particularly inaccurate, since the browser geolocates with the GPS too.

Comment: You are right. Those are not inaccurate but i guess the GPS is not the ONLY source for the browser. It has some other sources like, wi-Fi,Signal strength etc..

Comment: Well, yes. But most smartphones do the same thing, even for native apps, unless you go to lengths to prevent it. Is there any particular reason that you can only use GPS? Usually, you need the position, and the OS will use WiFi and cell triangulation to get an approximation, then GPS to hone in (which is significantly faster because it basically knows where it is already).

Comment: The other reason why I am asking that was, If there is a way to access the GPS in the device, then there should be a way to access the Camera in the Android tablet. We are planning to access the camera from web app which will take the pictures.

Comment: The other advantage with accessing the GPS is it will calculate the Miles, Speed and it will provide directions too.